# Network issues - only Chrome's google search works, resetting modem fixes the issue

Tags: networking, dns, cable-modem

#### Summary

I have a regular problem where my internet stops working on almost all websites, whether on wifi or wired to the router or wired straight to the modem. However, Chrome's Google search still lets me search for arbitrary things successfully. But I cannot hit google.com in curl or firefox. I want to say I've received Discord messages successfully while in a failed state. Unplugging and plugging back in the modem fixes the problem.

#### Details

Apologies for how long this is. I added as much detail as I've been able to record because I really have no idea what is causing this. This is what I've gathered:

I have a simple, common network setup: a wifi router and a cable modem. My router's DNS is set to Google's servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. My PC's DNS is set to my router.

I've attempted to use curl to hit one of the asset urls that work in Chrome on the Google site by "exporting as curl" one of the asset requests on the Google site using Chrome Dev Tools, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Getting headers/cookies right in curl can be a little tricky sometimes (combined with a bash->powershell conversion) so I'm not 100% sure if that's a reliable result.

I can do a `tracert stackoverflow.com` during network failure and it will go through all the ISP nodes, reporting all the full host names, all the way out to what appears to be SO's Varnish reverse proxy. When I reset the network and things are working again, the `tracert stackoverflow.com` output is the same as when it was in a failed state, so the failed state doesn't seem to affect tracert.

However `curl -I stackoverflow.com`, and `curl -I <varnish-IP-address>` timeout when the network is in a failed state. And then they work again when I reset the network. I thought it might be a DNS issue, but I would have thought the direct IP request would have worked in that case. Also, `curl -vvvv <somehost>` seems to resolve to the same IP during and not during the failed state.

Running `ipconfig /flushdns` did not fix the problem or break Chrome's Google search. Nor did `ipconfig /renew`. Setting router DNS to automatic/ISP *did* break Chrome's Google search.

I read about ISPs having MAC address limits, but all 4 of my wifi-compatible devices go down at once, which doesn't seem consistent with that problem.

It seems like either

1. The modem is blocking certain traffic but not others at the HTTP level somehow, which I wouldn't have thought was possible with SSL.
2. The modem is for some reason blocking DNS queries and Chrome aggressively caches the Google-related ones. But then why can't I curl the SO IP address directly?
3. The problem is happening at the ISP level because of high traffic or some other deep network magic.
4. The problem is not with the modem, but resetting the modem triggers something (DHCP allocation?) that causes a problem on the router to get fixed.
5. My house is infested with gnomes.

I have a theory that it happens more often when I am downloading a large amount of content, but I'm not 100% certain that's always the case. I am not sure if I can reproduce it at will, but it happens fairly often.

UPDATE:
Additionally, unplugging/plugging in the router does not fix the problem, though it does seem to break the Chrome google search. Also, resetting the router to factory settings only temporarily solved the problem, I believe because it required power cycling the modem.

Comment: Update the firmware on your router, make a record of settings, do a factory reset to original specs and then start it up again. I would add wireless devices slowly to get an idea whether the above suggestion fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the firmware and added a factory reset to my list for next time it happens.

Comment: I power cycled the router which didn't fix the problem. I then did a router factory reset, but it only fixed the problem for a few days. I believe the router factory reset probably temporarily worked because I had to do a modem power cycle as part of the router factory reset.

Comment: There are only four places the problem can exist: WAN-side DNS, router's DNS service, router's firewall, or the PC's firewall _(unlikely unless you've customized it)_. Try different DNS servers, such as [Cloudfare's](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/) _(rules out issue on the DNS server's side)_. If the issue persists, change PC's primary DNS to Cloudfare's _(rules out router's DNS service)_.